# How to use an API with pagination in RxDart on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I am using an API library for Flutter via RxDart in this way:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:gifs/resources/tenor_api.dart';
import 'package:tenor/tenor.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


class SearchResult {
  final _api = TenorApi().api;

  Stream<TenorResponse> _res;
  Stream<TenorResponse> get res => _res;

  // final _searchTerms = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _searchTerms = PublishSubject<String>();
  void searchTerm(String query) => _searchTerms.add(query);

  SearchResult() {
    _res = _searchTerms
        .debounce((_) => TimerStream(true, Duration(milliseconds: 250)))
        .switchMap((query) async* {
      yield await _api.searchGIF(query, limit: 10);
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _searchTerms.close();
  }

}
```

Everything works fine but I have an issue about retrieving the next paged search from the api. Based on the documentation of the API: https://pub.dev/documentation/tenor/latest/ the way to fetch the next page is something like:

```
// Future<TenorResponse?> fetchNext({int limit = 20});

// here the fetchNext function is used to call next set of GIF which is sequenced after current response

TenorResponse? firstSetResponse = await tenor. /*.... Functions used to get TenorResponse? ....*/

TenorResponse? nextResult = await firstSetResponse?.fetchNext();

nextResult?.results.forEach((tenorResult) {
  var title = tenorResult.title;
  var media = tenorResult.media;
  print('$title: gif : ${media?.gif?.previewUrl?.toString()}');
});
```

In my current "RxDart" code I am able to load the first page of a search, but how can I manage the situation when the new search has the same query of the previous one and just loading the next paged data?